# Can I change Nuget package place?

Tags: nuget

When I Enable nuget package restore, the nuget folder always in the diretory which the .sln file in.

but what I want to achieve is:

nuget folder in mysolution sub folder, How can I do that?

Comment: Is the "mysolution sub folder" a real folder or just one of the magical "solution folders" that only exist in visual studio's imagination? (such folders appear in solution explorer but have no reality on disk)

Answer (score 0):

The nuget folder location is hard coded as $(solutionDir)\.nuget. There is no way to change it.